# Java reverse the order of accessing a list in a for loop

Tags: java

I want to reverse the order of accessing a List inside a for()

This is my actual code

```
for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(states.size());
    states.get(i).update(true); // restore the first blockstate
    states.remove(i); // remove the first blockstate from the list
}
```

This code works, but I would like to reverse it. I already tried other ways, like using `i--` but it did not work. Can someone provide a suggestion?

Comment: You can use the built-in method [`Colletions.reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-).

Comment: As another note, doing `states.remove(i);` inside a `for` loop can potentially throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. If you need to go through a collection and remove things as you go along, you should stick to an iterator.

Comment: Do you want to do the same thing, but starting from the back?

Comment: @Tunaki I think OP wants to reverse the loop, not the list.

Comment: yes i want to start from back

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I already tried other ways, like using `i--` but it did not work.

Reversing a `for` loop consists of three steps:

- Change the initial value to the last value,
- Change the condition to stop after passing the initial value
- Reversing the increment/decrement (i.e. `++` becomes `--`)

In your code this change would look as follows:

```
for(int i = states.size()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    System.out.println(states.size());
    states.get(i).update(true); // restore the current blockstate
    states.remove(i); // remove the current blockstate from the list
}
```

Note that the last value reached in the original loop is `states.size()-1`, not `states.size()`, so `i` needs to start at `states.size()-1` as well.

Since your loop eventually clears out the list anyway, but does it one element at a time, you may get better clarity by deleting the call of `remove(i)`, replacing it with `states.clear()` after the loop.

```
for(int i = states.size()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    System.out.println(states.size());
    states.get(i).update(true); // restore the current blockstate
}
states.clear();
```

Comment: Yhea thats working but how would u do a interval between each loop? i have a new regenBlock(states).runTaskTimer(this, 40, 17); but now isnt working it does the loop very fast

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List list = Lists.reverse(states); 
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.size());
    list.get(i).update(true); // restore the first blockstate
    //list.remove(i); // remove the first blockstate from the list
 }
```

if u want to remove element when accessing element then u have to use iterator by using simple for it is not possible... it throws concurrent modification exception